# How Can I View All of the Files in a URL?

Tags: linux, wget

Is there a way to view all the files for a download location?

I can download files with WGET from: http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/drivers/D95_D110_D125/drivers/win7x64/pt_BR/D95-125CP_5.303.15.0_PS_x64.exe

I cannot view the files from the folder where I download the file, as accessing this location shows a 403:
http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/drivers/D95_D110_D125/drivers/win7x64/pt_BR/

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to view all the files for a download location?

`wget` (and similar programs) can only read/access files that the web server returns/allows. If the web server returns a `403 Forbidden` page in response to a directory listing request, there is no way for `wget` to obtain that directory information (literally, the page contains no links for `wget` to parse/follow).